# Jetty server seems to be attacked by ddos

Tags: java, jetty, ddos

Recently, I found my server which is built by jetty seems to be attacked.

After I can't get in my web-page, I found that was the "too many opened files" exception.

Then, I dumped the log from lsof.

```
java    1434 root  592u  IPv6          224516242          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->204.15.135.116:49241 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  593u  IPv6          224516243          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->204.15.135.116:49275 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  594u  IPv6          224516244          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->204.15.135.116:49312 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  595u  IPv6          224516245          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->204.15.135.116:49366 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  596u  IPv6          224516246          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->204.15.135.116:49398 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  597u  IPv6          224516247          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->204.15.135.116:49426 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  598u  IPv6          224516248          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->204.15.135.116:49465 (FIN_WAIT2)
...
...

java    1434 root  728u  IPv6          342047978          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->baiduspider-123-125-71-29.crawl.baidu.com:52473 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  729u  IPv6          344672761          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->baiduspider-123-125-71-34.crawl.baidu.com:38300 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  730u  IPv6          342159973          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->baiduspider-123-125-71-28.crawl.baidu.com:60379 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  731u  IPv6          342165176          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->baiduspider-220-181-108-157.crawl.baidu.com:30515 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  732u  IPv6          342494647          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->baiduspider-123-125-71-97.crawl.baidu.com:51496 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  733u  IPv6          342623082          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->baiduspider-220-181-108-141.crawl.baidu.com:28979 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  734u  IPv6          342499841          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->baiduspider-220-181-108-110.crawl.baidu.com:19578 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  735u  IPv6          342768198          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->baiduspider-220-181-108-155.crawl.baidu.com:56385 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  736u  IPv6          342874997          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->baiduspider-220-181-108-99.crawl.baidu.com:36623 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  737u  IPv6          343004455          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->baiduspider-220-181-108-103.crawl.baidu.com:56756 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  738u  IPv6          343215387          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->baiduspider-220-181-108-115.crawl.baidu.com:38924 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  739u  IPv6          343311431          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->baiduspider-123-125-71-47.crawl.baidu.com:46495 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  740u  IPv6          343115288          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->baiduspider-220-181-108-123.crawl.baidu.com:15823 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  741u  IPv6          343420236          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->baiduspider-123-125-71-56.crawl.baidu.com:35342 (FIN_WAIT2)
java    1434 root  742u  IPv6          343916808          0t0       TCP xx.xxxx.xx:87->baiduspider-220-181-108-139.crawl.baidu.com:49866 (FIN_WAIT2)
```

There are many FIN_WAIT2 state.

It seems someone was trying to build incomplete connections with my server.

I need to to know how to prevent the FIN_WAIT2 state, because it would crash the server.

My jetty version is 6.1.26. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this thread could help (although is for newer versions of jetty): https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=364921 Also, if you don't need to be crawled by baidu, google how to block them.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems happening with Jetty 6.X.

Jetty 7.6 doesn't have this problem.